# How to `getNativeSymbolInfo()` for a symbol in a `.so` from a built in R package?

Tags: r, shared-libraries, symbols

The following shows `_modelmatrix` is a symbol available in `stats.so`.

```
$ nm -g /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so | grep  modelmatrix
000000000004a080 T _modelmatrix
```

But I can not find it when I use `dyn.load()` to load the `stats.so` file in R.

```
R> dyn.load('/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so')
R> getNativeSymbolInfo('modelmatrix')
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no such symbol modelmatrix
```

However, doing the same thing for an external package works.

```
R> dyn.load('/Users/username/Library/R/3.2/library/rlecuyer/libs/rlecuyer.so')
R> getNativeSymbolInfo("user_unif_rand")
```

Does anybody know how to `getNativeSymbolInfo()` for a symbol in a `.so` from a built in R package?

Answer (score 2):

This:

> `000000000004a080 T _modelmatrix`

tells you that symbol `_modelmatrix` is defined in the library (it's likely a Fortran symbol, because it's prefixed with underscore). This:

> `R> getNativeSymbolInfo('modelmatrix')`

Looks for symbol `modelmatrix` (without underscore).

Why did you expect this to succeed? Shouldn't you be doing this instead?

```
R> getNativeSymbolInfo('_modelmatrix')
```

Comment: Because, I saw this. `R> getNativeSymbolInfo('_modelmatrix')
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no such symbol _modelmatrix`. Why don't you try the command yourself first?

Comment: @user1424739 "Why don't you..." because I don't have your version of R installed. Is this on Mac OSX by chance? My answer is wrong for OSX.